# Print console colors

Tags: linux, colors, console, tty, tput

Wrote a bash function to display the console colors.

But, it seems some of the colors are not possible to show that way! (?)

Also, note the strange "bright black"!

(Note: The below screendump is of xterm, but this is meant to be used in console mode. I had to use xterm to get a screendump. But it looks much the same.)

[image: clr]

```
function clr () {
  Color_names="bla red gre yel blu mag cya whi"
  Color_arr=($Color_names)
  for m in {0..15}
  do
    tput setaf $m
    echo -n ${Color_arr[$((m % 8))]}" "
  done
  echo
  tput sgr0
  cat /sys/module/vt/parameters/default_red \
      /sys/module/vt/parameters/default_grn \
      /sys/module/vt/parameters/default_blu | tr "," "\t"
}
```

Comment: Why do you think colors above 7 will work?  [man 5 terminfo](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/terminfo/) only mentions 0-7.

Comment: Well... it is clear now that that was where the shoe hurt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you check `tput colors`, you'll probably see that the answer is 8. The way to show the bright colors is by `tput bold`.

This shows all 8x8x2 combinations of foreground and background, normal and bold.

```
for cmd in sgr0 bold; do
  tput $cmd
  for i in $(seq 0 7); do
    for j in $(seq 0 7); do
      tput setaf $i; tput setab $j; echo -n " $i,$j "
    done
    tput sgr0; echo; tput $cmd
  done
done
```

Comment: I added `tput reset` because after breaking the lines 1) if the terminal output is scrolled up, the end of lines get filled with the last used color; 2) if the prompt sets no colors (or even if it sets, depending on the terminal) the next command will keep the last used color. I find it very ugly. Maybe `reset` was more than needed, I intended to use it as `\e[0m` equivalent. Update: you are right, should use `tput sgr0` instead.

Comment: Awesome stuff! I'll edit the question with your stuff when I've integrated it with my table values.

Answer (score 1):

See this blog post:
http://www.enigmacurry.com/2009/01/20/256-colors-on-the-linux-terminal/

Edit: if you have just 8 color result from `tput-color` you can use ncurses to solve your weakness! in ubuntu install it:

```
sudo apt-get install ncurses-term
```

and add the following line in your ~/.bashrc or ~/bash_profile:

```
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

and instead of your script you can use emacs command to see your colors. run emacs in terminal with `emacs -nw` and type command `M-x list-colors-display`

doesn't matter witch terminal do you have, this tools will work on all of your terminal emulators ;-)

Comment: Please summarize the article.  Answers should be more than just a link.

Comment: This blog post is about xterm. It doesn't apply to the Linux console.

Comment: OK, still an interesting topic and a good effort!

Answer (score 0):

There are several terminal descriptions which can be used for the Linux console.  The most commonly used one of course is set with [`TERM=linux`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-linux).

As an alternative, there is [`TERM=linux-16color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-linux-16color), which does the combinations of bold/color that you can see in @angus' answer.

Comparing `linux` and `linux-16color` with `infocmp` shows this:

```
comparing linux to linux-16color.
    comparing booleans.
    comparing numbers.
        colors: 8, 16.
        ncv: 18, 63.
        pairs: 64, 256.
    comparing strings.
        setab: '\E[4%p1%dm', '\E[4%p1%{8}%m%d%?%p1%{7}%>%t;5%e;25%;m'.
        setaf: '\E[3%p1%dm', '\E[3%p1%{8}%m%d%?%p1%{7}%>%t;1%e;21%;m'.
```

The `%t;5` and `%t;1` pieces use the blink- and bold-attributes (a feature of the display hardware) to get bright background and foreground colors depending on the value fed to `tput setab` and `tput setaf`.

Here is a screenshot done using the ncurses test-program with `linux-16color`:

[image: example of linux-16color]