# Printing colored text using script

Tags: shell, shell-script, quoting, escape-characters, echo

When  I type below command in the shell I get the OUTPUT in green color.

**Command**

```
echo "\033[32mCONNECTING TO abpwrk\033[m";
```

**Output**(in green color)

```
CONNECTING TO abpwrk
```

But if I use the same statement in a small one line script and execute it.Then I get the output(in white color).

```
\033[32mCONNECTING TO abpwrk\033[m
```

What am I missing in the script.Do I need to define some extra parameters to initiate colors ? I am using k-shell.

Comment: Post your script. I am sure that one is not interpreted by `ksh`. Try `echo -e "\033[32mCONNECTING TO abpwrk\033[m"` – if that works, your script is probably interpreted by `bash`.

Answer (score 4):

You probably are using different shells with different `echo` implementations. At least in `bash`'s implementation of echo, interpretation of escape sequences is not enabled by default (you have to enable it with the `-e` switch).

In any case, `printf` is generally more conformant between environments. Try using the following instead:

```
_host=abpwrk ; printf '\033[32mCONNECTING TO %s\033[m\n' "$_host"
```

Comment: What about `tput setaf` and `tput setab` (both followed by a digit)? @g4ur4v: Check out [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46215/print-console-colors) question.